# Difference between `Pin: release v` and `Pin: version` in apt preferences file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, preferences

I can't seem to find anything related to the difference between `Pin: version 5.8` and `Pin: release v=5.8` in the documentation for the apt preferences file.

Do they do the same thing or have differences?

Also there is a similar occurrence between `Pin: origin "origin"` and `Pin: release o=origin`.

Comment: See `man apt_preferences` and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Comment: I've looked in that but it didn't appear to answer the questions I am asking unless I have missed something

Comment: In the `man apt_preferences` around line 335+ there is a lot of your answers that you are asking.

Comment: Your question is way too broad... Please edit to make it limited to one question only

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: @Terrance I see it talks about specifying a version via `Pin: release v=` but I see no mention on `Pin: version`?

Comment: Usually what is in the `man file` is what is supported in the settings, etc.  The `Pin: version` may not be supported anymore.

Comment: `Pin: version` is still supported. Just tested on 21.10. Also check https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration?action=show&redirect=AptPreferences#apt_preferences_.28APT_pinning.29 .

Answer (score 4):

After more digging I've figured it out.

## TL;DR

`Pin: release X=Y` filters against fields of the Release file using shorthand notation. In the release file the version should be the version of the *release*. e.g.) for Debian bullseye you could have `Pin: release v=11`, or for Ubuntu Jammy you could have `Pin: release v=22.04`. Origin should the author or vendor name. e.g.) `Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam`.

`Pin: version X` filters against the package version. e.g.) `Pin: version 1:91`.

`Pin: origin X` filters against the hostname. e.g.) `Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net`.

## Release File

In the `Determination of Package Version and Distribution Properties` section of `man apt_preferences` we find this.

> The locations listed in the sources.list(5) file should provide Packages and Release files to describe the packages available at that location.

So each location (which has an origin) has a [release file](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format?action=show&redirect=RepositoryFormat#A.22Release.22_files) for each release available. In that link, we see the release file is hosted at `dists/$DIST/InRelease`.

On my local machine we have

```
$ apt-cache policy
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-mozillateam,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Firefox ESR and Thunderbird stable builds,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
```

Here, you can see my local machine is using the `jammy` release. So the relevant release file is located at `dists/jammy/InRelease`. This gives us this file here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease.

That release file is created by the person hosting the repository and contains meta-information about the distribution. Some of the information is optional, and some is not. Some of the optional fields include:

- Origin
- Label
- Version
- Suite
- Codename

And some of the non-optional fields include:

- Components

This is what you filter against when you specify `Pin: release X=` in your preferences file. It is also described when you run `apt-cache policy`. In the example above, we have:

- Origin: `o=LP-PPA-mozillateam`
- Label: `l=Firefox ESR`
- Version: `v=22.04`
- Suite: `a=jammy`
- Codename: `n=jammy`
- Components: `c=main`

*NB: I couldn't find anything in the man page in relation to the `b=` field in the output of the `apt-cache policy` command.*

## Origin

As well as the above information in the release file, the location also has an origin. This is also included in the output of the `apt-cache policy` command. As you can see for the example above, it is `ppa.launchpad.net`.

This is what you filter against when you include `Pin: origin X` in your preferences file.

In the `The Effect of APT Preferences` section of the man page, it has this useful sentence:

> This should not be confused with the Origin of a distribution as specified in a Release file. What follows the "Origin:" tag in a Release file is not an Internet address but an author or vendor name, such as "Debian" or "Ximian".

## Version

Back to the `Determination of Package Version and Distribution Properties` section of the man page.

As mentioned above, it states:

> The locations listed in the sources.list(5) file should provide Packages and Release files to describe the packages available at that location.

So as well as this release file, we also have a packages file. The man page goes on to say:

> Only two lines in each record [of the package file] are relevant for setting APT priorities:
>
> the Package: line
>
> gives the package name
>
> the Version: line
>
> gives the version number for the named package

This is different to what it says for the Version field of the *Release* file, for which it says

> the Version: line
>
> names the release version. For example, the packages in the tree might belong to Debian release version 11.

If we find one of these package files, we can see this. For the package above, for my architecture, it is here: http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz

Within that compressed archive, we have a `Packages` file which contains a list of all the packages available and their versions (and lots of other information). Here is part of one of the many packages available:

```
Package: thunderbird
Priority: optional
Section: mail
Installed-Size: 227239
Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team <ubuntu-mozillateam@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1:91.5.1+build1-0ubuntu1
```

This version is what you fiter against when you include `Pin: version X` in your preferences file.

If you run `apt-cache policy` on a specific package, you can see the versions available for that package.

```
$ apt-cache policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:78.14.0-1~deb11u1
  Candidate: 1:78.14.0-1~deb11u1
  Version table:
     1:91.5.1+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     1:91.5.1-1+b2 10
         10 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
     1:91.5.0-2~deb11u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:78.14.0-1~deb11u1 900
        900 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

## Confusion with Version

It appears that the version specified in the release file doesn't always appear to be correct. For example, for Google Chrome, we have this:

```
$ apt-cache policy
 900 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
```

I'm not sure what this version is supposed to represent, as it doesn't match the versions in the packages file:

```
$ grep "Package\|Version" /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
Package: google-chrome-beta
Version: 99.0.4844.17-1
Package: google-chrome-stable
Version: 98.0.4758.80-1
Package: google-chrome-unstable
Version: 100.0.4867.0-1
```

Comment: If, for Ubuntu 22.04, it's `release v=22.04` then it looks like that's meant to be a distribution version and not a package version. I can imagine, e.g., a third-party  for distributing something like, say, Nodejs or PostgreSQL, setting up multiple channels for each major release of the software and setting the distribution version accordingly. Chrome doesn't have that kind of a release model, so they probably just set a dummy value of 1.0.